# Date format in SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, sql

We need a specific format date to personalize our emails, for example, the US date format is `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` and we need to display `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Is it possible to change the date format directly in the DE through the Query so that we can use personalization strings (and no ampscript)?

We tried in the query, in the Select part something like `format(Date_field,'dd/MM/yyy') as Datefincarte`, and we had a "system error".

Answer (score 6):

*Date* data types in SFMC are [**DateTime**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (or DateTime2) data types behind the scenes, so the time is always included.  It's best to use AMPscript to format these, as you can't dictate the format stored in the data extension unless you store them as Text.

I generally just use the [**formatDate()**](https://ampscript.guide/formatDate/) function in AMPscript:

```
%%[

 var @date_field
 set @date_field = AttributeValue("date_field")
 set @date_field = formatDate(@date_field, "s") /* s = short date*/

]%%
<br>The date is %%=v(@date_field)=%%
```

Depending on the timezone offset of your DateTime value, you may need to use the [**LocalDateToSystemDate**](https://ampscript.guide/LocalDateToSystemDate) function to align the time to your SFMC account's timezone.

```
%%[

 var @date_field
 set @date_field = AttributeValue("date_field")
 set @date_field = formatDate(LocalDateToSystemDate(@date_field), "iso")

]%%
```

If you want to store the date as a string in your query, you can create a new `date_field_str` column (or something like that) in your data extension and use a query like this to store it as Text:

```
select
convert(varchar (10), d.date_field, 1) as date_field_str
from YOURDATAEXTENSIONNAMEHERE d
```

The `1` argument on the `convert` function specifies the format.  Formats are listed on [**this**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) page.

**Reference**

- [**FormatDate**](https://ampscript.guide/formatDate/)
- [**T-SQL convert**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)